# Bitbucket Cloud - Adding Custom Fields

Tags: bitbucket-cloud

Is there a way in Bitbucket Cloud to add custom fields.  It seems to be possible in Bitbucket server but I can't seem to find a way (with or without add ons) to do it in cloud.

We have a need to capture some additional data on Pull requests and don't want it to get lost in the description and comment fields so we'd like specific fields to utilize for this data.